# AWS EC2 mongoDB - Script efficiency

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

By client's request instead of using DynamoDB we configured a mongoDB on an AWS EC2 instance.
Said instance is an **m5a.large** which has 2 vCPUs and 8GB memory. As stated earlier it's got mongoDB installed, as well as Python and a few libraries to work with mongo.

The issue began when we started filling a mongo collection with a csv of about 2-3mill records and 14 columns. (About 400mb)
While the instance is not stopping or raising an OOM Error, the script that fills the collection stops at about 90% of the records and there is not error raised whatsoever.

I believe it has something to do with the script we are using to do it and I was wondering if someone could give me a helping hand either by giving me another -more efficient- way of doing it or by confirming it's just an instance memory limitation.

```
import json
from mongoengine import *
from app.config import *
import pandas as pd
from app.model import Users

import time

conn = connect(
    db=db_name,
    username=username,
    password=password,
    authentication_source=authentication_source,
    host=host,
)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    t0 = time.time()
    print("Time taken %8.8f seconds" % (time.time() - t0))

    # CSV to JSON Conversion
    df = pd.read_csv(
        "csv.csv",
        sep="|",
        encoding="latin1",
    )


    df = df.rename(
        columns={
            "c1":"C1",
        }
    )

    rows = df.to_json(orient="records")
    rows = json.loads(rows)

    Users.objects(cond=True).update(**{"cond": False})

    for row in rows:
        Users(row).register()
    print("Time taken %8.8f seconds" % (time.time() - t0))
```

**Note: Users class inherits from mongoengine's DynamicDocument**

Comment: a different approach you may want to consider is to convert the CSV to json file.  Then use mongoimport to import the JSON file.

Comment: No need to convert, mongoimport supports CSV directly with the `--type` command line option

Comment: Would you mind giving an example of how mongoimport would work? I'm not an expert whatosever and the CSV is indeed being converted to json file.